# Working Directories in R using for loop

Tags: r, directory, subdirectory

I have a zip file which I am unpacking then I am using a for loop to go through the directories in the working directory and then change the working directory to the new folder that I have just unpacked. However, it doesn't seem to like it.

Below are the two codes that I have used, one of them ends up with an error whereas the second one doesn't do what I want it to do. I think I am perhaps mixing some Python logic?

```
for (i in list.files("./")){
  if (endsWith(tolower(i),"zip")){
    unzip(i)
    cat("Unzipped",i,"\n")
  }
}

for (i in list.dirs(getwd())){
    cat("This is i",i,"\n")
    Root <- setwd(i)
    cat("This is ROOT",Root,"\n")

}

print(Root)
```

The result I get from running the above code is as follows:

```
This is i F:/Testing with R 
This is ROOT F:/Testing with R 
This is i F:/Testing with R/ABC_Data 
This is ROOT F:/Testing with R
```

As you can see, I would like it to loop through the folders and make ABC_Data the working directory so that I can then loop through the files but it doesn't like it.

The second code that I tried after going through some pages on Stackoverflow was amended using paste0() to below, which worked till a certain point but then gave an error:

```
> for (i in list.files("./")){
+   if (endsWith(tolower(i),"zip")){
+     unzip(i)
+     cat("Unzipped",i,"\n")
+   }
+ }
Unzipped GVA_BillData.zip 
> 
> for (i in list.dirs(getwd())){
+     cat("This is i",i,"\n")
+     Root <- paste0(path.expand(i),"/")
+     cat("This is ROOT",Root,"\n")
+   
+ }
This is i F:/Testing with R 
This is ROOT F:/Testing with R/ 
This is i F:/Testing with R/ABC_Data 
This is ROOT F:/Testing with R/ABC_Data/ 
> 
> print(Root)
[1] "F:/Testing with R/ABC_Data/"
> 
> File_count <- 0
> for (a in list.files(Root)){
+   print(a)
+   if (endsWith(tolower(a),"csv")){
+     if (length(grep("service file",tolower(a)) > 0)){
+       Import <- read.csv(a, header = TRUE)
+       for (i in 1:nrow(Import)){
+         Import_Date <- Import[1,4]
+         if (File_count == 0){
+           write.table(c(Import[i,],Import_Date,a),"Output.csv",append = TRUE,sep = ",",row.names = FALSE,col.names = TRUE)
+           File_count <- File_count + 1
+         } else (write.table(c(Import[i,],Import_Date,a),"Output.csv",append = TRUE,sep = ",",row.names = FALSE,col.names = FALSE))
+           }
+         }
+       }
+   }
[1] "1234_126311.csv"
[1] "Service File.csv"
Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") :
  cannot open file 'Service File.csv': No such file or directory
> print("Finished")
[1] "Finished"
```

So, as you can see in the second code it jumps to the folder but throws the error message. I have tried using simply `path.expand(i)` as well but that didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the assignment when using `setwd()` is causing the issue. Adjusting you first code to this:

```
for (i in list.dirs(getwd())){
    cat("This is i",i,"\n")
    setwd(i)
    Root <- getwd()
    cat("This is ROOT",Root,"\n")    
}
```

seems to work for me.

The problem is not that the `setwd()` isn't working, it's that the assignment is returning the old working directory. The docs (`?setwd`) say "`setwd` returns the current directory before the change". (Thanks @Tensibai.) See the following example:

```
setwd("c:/")
getwd()
# [1] "c:/"
z<-setwd("c:/Users/")
z
# [1] "c:/"
getwd()
# [1] "c:/Users"
```

Comment: Thanks bud, it worked for me too.

Any reason why it wasn't letting me do it in the first place? I mean was it because I was assigning a value by calling a function??